# rm: cannot remove: Operation not permitted. No chattr set

Tags: linux, command-line, debian

The file returns `Operation not permitted` for shred and rm. `lsattr` only has e, so the file isn't immutable. How can I delete this file, or at the very least make one of my own. I will lose access to it soon after posting so follow-ups may not be possible.

Edit: Strangely enough the file is completely writable and modifiable. I found it initially through a cronjob, but when I had tried to look at the crontab it was empty.

Comment: just for fun, what is the output of `which chattr`? The error "No chattr set" is not common (does not appear on Google) so I'm wondering if your system can't find it, or if its damaged.

Comment: Frank: I believe that the OP isn’t getting “chattr not set” as an error message. I believe that he’s getting “Operation not permitted” as an error message, and is summarizing (in the title) what he elaborates in the body of the question; namely, that the file doesn’t have any attribute(s) set that would easily explain the inability to remove it. Leo: Please clarify. What user are you running as (root or yourself)? What are the owner and mode of the file and the containing directory? Can you create, rename and remove other files in that directory? Is it a remote filesystem or anything else odd?